# Popup with iframe: Use of multiple @Html.AntiForgeryToken() at once

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, antiforgerytoken

I have a page that when loads generates an anti forgery token with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. This happens in the layout file. The page can open a few popups with an iframe in. This iframe generates its own anti forgery token with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.

On the page where you can open the popup, the user can log out. The log out request include the anti forgery token generated when this page loaded.

Given that I do this:

- Load the page where the popups can be opened (an anti forgery token is generated)
- Open a popup with an iframe (a new anti forgery token is generated in the iframe)
- Log out from the page where I can open the popups

The log out succeeds. Why is that? Wouldn't the new token replace the old one at the server? Or are the anti forgery token I validate against stored as a cookie in the browser, so that when I pass the anti forgery token value with the log out request, the browser also passes the matching anti forgery token cookie that I compare against?

I'm on ASP.NET 4.5.2 and MVC 5.2.3.

Comment: `(a new anti forgery token is generated in the iframe)` What makes you think this occurs?

Comment: @mjwills Because I load a page in the iframe that uses `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.

Comment: Both will get the same token.

Answer (score 0):

[Seems like it is saved in a cookie.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages#web-stack-runtime-xsrf-mitigations) This is *not* from the article for .NET Core, though it *might* work the same way there.

> The ASP.NET Web Stack Runtime uses a variant of the synchronizer token
>   pattern to defend  against XSRF attacks. The general form of the
>   synchronizer token pattern is that two anti-  XSRF tokens are
>   submitted to the server with each HTTP POST (In addition to the 
>   authentication token): one token as a cookie, and the other as a form
>   value. The token  values generated by the ASP.NET runtime are not
>   deterministic or predictable by an  attacker. When the tokens are
>   submitted, the server will allow the request to proceed only  if both
>   tokens pass a comparison check.